# What are the possible exceptions in an Integer attribution?

Tags: java

While refactoring some code, i was asked to make changes to the exception handling , changing some of the catch clauses to get the most specific exception possible in the try block. But then i came across this snippet:

```
try {
        if (flagYear) {
            if (Day[0] == Month[0]) {
                if (Day[1] != null) {
                    Month = Month[0];
                    Day = Day[1];
                } else {
                    Month = Month[1];
                    Day = Day[0];
                }
            } else {
                Month = Month[0];
                Day = Day[0];
            }
        } else {
            if (Day[0] == Month[0]) {
                if (Month[1] != null) {
                    Month = Month[1];
                    Day = Day[0];
                } else {
                    Month = Month[0];
                    Day = Day[1];
                }
            } else {
                Month = Month[0];
                Day = Day[0];
            }
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        throw new ExampleException();
    }
```

The variables are declared as:

```
Integer[] Day = new Integer[2];
Integer[] Month = new Integer[2];
```

The javadoc on the Integer class only references the NumberFormatException.

So the question is: What is the most specific exception that can catch all the exceptions in a block with simple Integer comparisons and attributions?

Comment: Question unclear; however, maybe this will help you: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and `NumberFormatException` are both children of `RuntimeException`. HOWEVER: all three are unchecked exceptions, which are normally not meant to be thrown or caught. I fail to understand the purpose of the exercise here.

Comment: By convention, variable names should start with lowercase letters.  It is especially bad with the StackOverflow syntax highlighting which is coloring them like type declarations, making it harder to read.

Comment: variables should be declared in camel case fashion. in this case day and month should both be small d and m respectively

Comment: Also, how can you assign an `Integer` (Month[0]) to an array of `Integer`s?  Your code shouldn't even compile, let alone throw a runtime exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NumberFormatException only occurs when you try to parse a String into an Integer

In this piece of code, the only risk is to have an `Integer` that does not really represent a month (13,14,15) or a day (32,33,34...)

In this case, you can for example throw a `IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: `IllegalArgumentException` is an unchecked exception: you should not throw one unless you are absolutely sure of what you are doing.

Comment: I agree with that but a common rule with exception is to catch exception only if you want to do useful things with them. In this case, I do not see what he/she could do except than catching/logging/rethrowing. He/She has the possibility to just ignore the exception and let it propagate if happens.

Answer (score 2):

Why are we catching runtime exceptions? I know this is an issue for debate, but, having to do that to me implys incorrect handling. A simple sanity check would save you gobbling up all run time exceptions in one catch :/

Answer (score 1):

Although catching `RuntimeException` and re-throwing custom exception looks strange for this code fragment this is the less significant problem of this extremely ugly code. (I am sorry: nothing private, only business).

- RuntimeException cannot be thrown here, so remove try/catch block at all.
- Rename variables. I java all variables should start with small letter.
- Simplify your code. Both branches or `if` look exactly the same. The difference in indexes only.
- Do not compare primitive wrappers with `==`. This will *sometimes* work just because `Integer` class has internal cache of low values (I think from 0 till 256 or 512...)

etc, etc.